# How to automate split by delimiter in Excel (equivalent of =SPLIT in gSheets)

Tags: excel, excel-formula, split, formula

Having recently moved from full-time Google Sheets -> Excel, I'm still getting used to a few things being missing... I'm needing to split cells in Excel using a delimiter of space (" ").

I'm looking for a way to do this with a formula in Excel. The Excel equivalent of `=SPLIT(#REF, " ")` in Google Sheets. I'm aware Excel has a "Text to Columns" feature, but I'm trying to fully automate a project, to reduce the chance of human error, so would be after a formula instead.

**Additionally, I need to maximise the number of splits to 4, so it ignores everything after the 4th split.**

I've tried a few things, such as using `=LEFT(#REF,FIND(" ",#REF))`,`=RIGHT(#REF,FIND(" ",#REF))`, and `=MID(#REF, SEARCH(" ",#REF) + 1, SEARCH(" ",#REF,SEARCH(" ",#REF)+1) - SEARCH(" ",#REF) - 1)`. The issue is, the number of spaces within the cell can vary. Please see an example table below:

| ToSplit | Split #1 | Split #2 | Split #3 | Split #4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Hello | Hello |  |  |  |
| World | World |  |  |  |
| Hello World | Hello | World |  |  |
| Hello World FOO BAR BAZ | Hello | World | FOO | BAR |
| This Data Wants To Be Different | This | Data | Wants | To |

Is there any way to obtain this functionality within Excel, please? Thanks!

Comment: Which version of Excel?

Comment: Should have mentioned in the OP - It's m365. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Multiple ways, one is to use `FILTERXML()`:

[image]

Formula in `B2`:

```
=TRANSPOSE(FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(A2," ","</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s[position()<5]"))
```

This assumes ms365's spilling dynamic arrays. However, you could also use, for example:

```
=IFERROR(FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE($A2," ","</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s["&COLUMN(A1)&"]"),"")
```

Drag down and right.

---

More information on `FILTERXML()` and another custom `SPLIT()` function, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61837696/9758194) Q&A.

Comment: Amazing. Thank you so much. Didn't think to use `FILTERXML()` here. The first solution works perfectly. Much appreciated for the quick response.